# How do I make a `Copy` value inaccessible after use?

Tags: rust, idioms

```rust
struct S {
    foo: i32,
    // ... other fields
}


fn f(s: S) {
    // transform foo
    let new_foo = biz_logic(s.foo);
    // from now on, the code should read `new_foo` whenever it needs `s.foo`,
    // how do I "drop" the `s.foo` to prevent misuse?
    // obviously `drop(s.foo)` won't work since it is `Copy`
    // is there any idiom to do this?
    drop(s.foo);

    // OK
    let _ = ... new_foo ...;
    
    // Not OK
    let _ = ... s.foo ...;
}
```

Is there less known rust feature that let's you achieve the same result as drop() on a Copy?

Comment: Why not update `s.foo` in place? e.g. `std::mem::replace(&mut s.foo, new_foo);` and then only use `s.foo` afterwards?

Comment: Also, if it's an error to reuse a value of foo after it's been copied, then it shouldn't implement `Copy` at all.

Comment: @alter_igel: In this case, for a plain `i32`, it's likely *contextually* inappropriate to reuse it in this function, not *generally* inappropriate to do so (in other functions).

Comment: `Copy` data is supposed to represent pure information that can be indiscriminately duplicated and used regardless of its origin. If you want a type whose values can only exist in one place, use a data type that is not `Copy`, e.g. using the newtype idiom: <https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/new_types.html>.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the properties of an existing type, you're looking for the [newtype pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/behavioural/newtype.html). We can make a newtype wrapper of `i32` that behaves like `i32` but without the `Copy` implementation.

```
struct MyI32Resource(pub i32);
```

Then the type of `s.foo` can be `MyI32Resource`, which obeys Rust's default move semantics since we haven't implemented `Copy` for it. You can implement whatever `i32`-like traits you need on `MyI32Resource` to delegate to the inner field. Likewise, you can `impl Deref` to be able to deref your new resource type into an `i32`.

This approach should only be used for situations where it's semantically inappropriate to use the existing value after moving. That is, where you're truly thinking of the `i32` as a resource of some kind that truly can't be copied (Unix-style file descriptors are a great example of this; they're just integers, but semantically we want to impose resource-like constraints on them).

If you're just worried about someone reusing the same *name* in a particular function, then this approach is likely overkill, and Filipe's approach is cleaner for that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not interested in the rest of `s`, then destructuring and dropping will work:

```rust
fn f(s: S) {
    let S { foo, .. } = s;
    drop(s);

    // okay
    println!("{foo}");
    
    // not okay
    // println!("{}", s.foo);
}
```

Unfortunately, if you want to get at the rest of `s` (assuming some of it isn't `Copy`) this approach won't work, since the destructuring assignment will result in a partial move that will leave `s.foo` accessible and `s` unable to be manually dropped.

A better bet is probably destructuring in the function signature and shadowing:

```rust
fn f(S { foo, .. }: S) {
    let foo = biz_logic(foo);

    // foo is now result of biz_logic and foo from S is unreachable
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if `S` has a `Drop` impl, then you can't destructure or move out of it. (Though there are plans to allow that with `ManuallyDrop`).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use variable shadowing. However, you can't shadow `s.foo`, so unless you're willing to replace its value with `new_foo` and keep using `s.foo`, you can bind `s.foo` to a local variable, `foo`, then shadow it with the result of `biz_logic`:

```rust
fn f(s: S) {
    let foo = s.foo;

    // Use `foo` for whatever
    // ...

    // Shadow `foo` so the old value can't be accessed anymore.
    let foo = biz_logic(foo);

    // Usages of `foo` will always access the new `foo`.
}
```

Comment: But `s.foo` is still accessible.